# Wants to display this data in HTML Ajax jquery request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
{"response":{"refno":"hfc","status":"Status : Reference number does not exist."}}
```

I have made a request to a webpage, the webpage returns a response in this format. How can i display this in HTML format whether table or normal. I am showing my ajax code below. Made a request to a webpage using curl php. Tried some methods didnt succeed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $('#st_epic').submit(function(){
        var requestId = $("#epic").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/rand.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { requestId:requestId},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var trHTML = '';

                $.each(data.response:, function (i, item) {    
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.refno[i] + '</td><td>' + data.status[i] + '</td></tr>';
                });

                $('#epic_result').append(trHTML);
            },

            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.responseText);
            }
        });
})
```

Don't have much knowledge about javascript. so confused.

Comment: you should access like `data.response.refno` or something

Comment: Tried didn't worked

Comment: See [Riggs's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106603/wants-to-display-this-data-in-html-ajax-jquery-request#41106685).

Answer (score 0):

You are making things unnecesarily difficult. The returned data is a simple object within an object that has 2 properties.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $('#st_epic').submit(function(){
        var requestId = $("#epic").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/rand.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { requestId:requestId},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.response.refno + '</td><td>' + data.response.status + '</td></tr>';
                $('#epic_result').append(trHTML);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```